# Lumen Micro Framework => php artisan key:generate

Tags: php, lumen

I'm trying out the PHP micro Framework Lumen (from Laravel).

One of my first steps was to look into the `.env.example` file and make a copy of it to have my `.env` file. There is a variable APP_KEY just like there is in Laravel. Now I tried out the simple command `php artisan key:generate` to get my new key But I ran into the following error message:

> **[InvalidArgumentException]** There are no commands defined in the "key"
>   namespace.

Does some one know how I can generate keys for Lumen?

**Update with solution**

So I found my favorite solution for this problem. On the command line (Linux) I run `php -r "echo md5(uniqid()).\"\n\";"` what gives me something like this `7142720170cef01171fd4af26ef17c93`.

If you are going to use Lumen more often, you may want to create an alias in your `.bashrc`, which is located in your home directory `/home/USERNAME`. To do so, you can open the file with `nano ~/.bashrc` or `vi ~/.bashrc` and copy the following alias at the end of the file, `alias phpkey='php -r "echo md5(uniqid()).\"\n\";"'`. Now you can use the command `phpkey` which will give you a 32 character long random string :)

Comment: Using a fast hash function, like md5, does not increase entropy and `uniqid` is a low-entropy source of "randomness". Please use the solution provided by @lukasgeiter as `str_random` draws bytes from a cryptographically secure random number generator.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

The Laravel command is fairly simple. It just generates a random 32 character long string. You can do the same in Lumen. Just temporarily add a route like this:

```
$router->get('/key', function() {
    return \Illuminate\Support\Str::random(32);
});
```

Then go to `/key` in your browser and copy paste the key into your `.env` file.
Afterwards remove the route.

Obviously you could also use some random string generator online. [Like this one](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/random-string-generator/)

Comment: Nice solution :) But I realy was looking for a method to do it the "laravel/lumen" way ;)

Comment: There is none. Lumen needs to be light so it's up to the developer to do such things as generating keys...

Comment: In recent version $app is changed to $router. Rest is correct.

Comment: Small improvements
```if (!app()->environment('prod'))
    $router->get('/key', function() {
        return 'APP_KEY=base64:'. base64_encode(\Illuminate\Support\Str::random(32));
    });```

Answer (score 42):

Firstly, you have to register your **key generator command**, put this [Lumen Key Generator Commands](https://gist.github.com/krisanalfa/0407dd822f2888226f45) to `app/Console/Commands/KeyGenerateCommand.php`. To make this command available in `artisan`, change `app\Console\Kernel.php`:

```
/**
 * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\KeyGenerateCommand',
];
```

After that, configure your application so that `Illuminate\Config\Repository` instance has `app.key` value. To do this, change `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
| that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
| application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
|
*/

$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

$app->configure('app');
```

After that, copy your `.env.example` file to `.env`:

```
cp .env.example .env
```

> Ignore this step if you already use `.env` file.

Enjoy you `key:generate` command via:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

---

### Edit

You may use [Lumen Generator](https://github.com/flipboxstudio/lumen-generator). It covers so much commands you are missing from Laravel.

Comment: I would go with this answer rather, it's the laravel implementation and it teaches you a bit about console commands are structured and where they go in the context of your app. It is really cool once you dive into it :D

Comment: Nice solution! thanks for sharing. One tiny thing: I would use KeyGenerateCommand::class instead of the hardcoded class name in `$commands` ;)

Comment: this won't work if key was empty. Use this to replace the key: str_replace('APP_KEY='.env('APP_KEY'), 'APP_KEY='.$key, file_get_contents($path))

Comment: In Lumen I get the following error: `There are no commands defined in the "key" namespace.`

Comment: getting error 'There are no commands defined in the "key" namespace.'

Comment: @krisanalfa Thank you very much! However, with the latest version of lumen(8.0), it will trigger Method App\Console\Commands\KeyGenerateCommand::__invoke() does not exist. To resolve this, change the function name from "fire" to "handle". This will resolve the problem. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 33):

Simply use PHP CLI. Run this from your local or a remote command line to generate a random 32-character Lumen APP_KEY:

```
php -r "echo bin2hex(random_bytes(16));"
```

Output: bae48aba23b3e4395b7f1b484dd25192

Works with PHP 7.x on Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 28):

An easy solution is just running PHP code from the terminal (without using `tinker`, because that is not available with Lumen):

```
php -r "require 'vendor/autoload.php'; echo str_random(32).PHP_EOL;"
```

It uses Laravel's `Str::random()` function that makes use of the secure `random_bytes()` function.

Comment: Oneliner with base64encoded output for Lumen >= 5.4: `php -r "require 'vendor/autoload.php'; echo base64_encode(str_random(32)).PHP_EOL;"`

Answer (score 18):

For me the easiest way to generate a Lumen key is typing on console one of these commands:

```
date | md5
date | md5sum
```

or

`openssl rand -base64 24`

depending of your environment. In my case, I aways use `date | md5` on mac

Comment: Don't forget to base64 encode the md5 key for Lumen > 5.4, eg. `php -r "echo base64_encode(\"[YOUR-MD5-STRING]\");"` - add it prefixed with `base64:` in your `.env` file..

Answer (score 13):

The APP_KEY generation is a step of development process (I don't think that creating temporarily routes is a practical way to do it). The function `str_random` can help us, but this function is part of Laravel/Lunmen framework. 
I recommend running tinker

`php artisan tinker`

and then run the function

`>>> str_random(32)`

The result is the key you're looking for.

`=> "y3DLxnEczGWGN4CKUdk1S5GbMumU2dfH"`

Comment: But to even get tinker to work with Lumen you need to add it.  https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8566

Comment: Yep, finally I found myself using `date | md5sum` on terminal and pasting the result into .env

Comment: Thanks for the answer Cosmitar

Comment: In Lumen I get the following error: `Command "tinker" is not defined.`. But then I go to a Laravel project folder and it does work! I copied the string and then I got back to the Lumen folder.

Answer (score 5):

To generate key and use laravel command you need to install one package. The details are as below:

1. You have to install package `composer require flipbox/lumen-generator`
2. You have to add `$app->register(Flipbox\LumenGenerator\LumenGeneratorServiceProvider::class);` into `bootstrap/app.php` file.

Link: https://github.com/flipboxstudio/lumen-generator

Answer (score 3):

All I do on mac is execute this command in the terminal:

```
date | md5 | pbcopy
```

This copies the value into the clipboard and so you can easily paste the key into the `.env` file.

Answer (score 2):

I have used these commands:

```
php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"

php -r "echo password_hash(uniqid(), PASSWORD_BCRYPT).\"\n\";"
```

The command generates a key similar to this:

> $2y$10$jb3kw/vUANyzZ4ncMa4rwuR09qldQ2OjX8PGrVB5dIlSnUAPCGjFe

Answer (score 1):

This answer was inspired by @thomas-venturini 's update to the question. Here's a bash script that takes care of creating `.env` and updating it with an `APP_KEY` using the aforementioned PHP command and the UNIX `sed` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function generate_app_key {
    php -r "echo md5(uniqid()).\"\n\";"
}

APP_KEY=$(generate_app_key)

sed -e s/APP_KEY=.*$/APP_KEY=${APP_KEY}/g .env.example > .env
```

Hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Run `php -a` to start up interactive php playground.

Then run `echo substr(md5(rand()), 0, 32);` to generate a 32 character string.

You can then copy/paste into the `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

1.Open your terminal setup file:

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

2.Create an alias for generating random strings:

```
# Lumen Key Generate
alias lumen-key="php -r \"require 'vendor/autoload.php'; echo base64_encode(str_random(32)).PHP_EOL;\""
```

3.Get a key whenever you need:

```
~/your-lumen-project via  v7.3.0
➜ lumen-key
VkxTYWZZSnhVNVEzRThXelBGZVJDVGZVYTNTcm9peHY=
```

> You can also remove the third step by adding the key directly in `.env` using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

[Flipbox\LumenGenerator]

Fix error: there are no comands defined...

[boostrap/app] Check if you register the Flipbox\LumenGenerator after return $app. If so move the Service provider register before return app...

```
/**
 * Configure extra LARAVEL commands to a lumen app
 * Check avaliable commands in git: flipboxstudio lumen-generator
 */
if($app->environment() !== 'production'){
    $app->register(Flipbox\LumenGenerator\LumenGeneratorServiceProvider::class);
}

return $app;
```

Lumen 8.0 / flipbox/lumen-generator 8.2

Answer (score 0):

It Worked 100%

Simply install the flipbox/lumen-generator package

`composer require flipbox/lumen-generator`.

Inside your bootstrap/app.php file, add:

```
$app->register(Flipbox\LumenGenerator\LumenGeneratorServiceProvider::class);
```

Then after you can able to run php artisan commands,
more info: https://github.com/flipboxstudio/lumen-generator

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering the error message "ERROR There are no commands defined in the 'key' namespace" when running the `php artisan key:generate` command in Lumen, it typically means that the command is not registered or available in your application.

In Lumen, the `key:generate` command is not included by default since Lumen doesn't come with the same set of commands as Laravel. However, generating an app key is still necessary for certain features to work correctly.

To generate an app key in Lumen, you can follow an alternative approach:

1. Open the terminal or command prompt.
2. Navigate to your Lumen project's root directory.
3. Run the following command:

   ```
   php -r "echo bin2hex(random_bytes(32));"
   ```

   This command generates a random 32-byte string and displays it as a hexadecimal value.
4. Copy the generated key.
5. Open your `.env` file and find the line that starts with `APP_KEY=`. If the line doesn't exist, you can add it manually.
6. Replace the value after `APP_KEY=` with the generated key you copied.

   For example:

   ```
   APP_KEY=your-generated-key
   ```
7. Save the `.env` file.

By following these steps, you can manually generate an app key in Lumen and update it in your `.env` file.

Please note that while this alternative method allows you to generate an app key, it's important to ensure that the key is kept secure and not shared publicly.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Command for it.

I think this is better than installing a package just for this... Because you will run this only one time.

So, you need to do:

Create **app\Console\Commands\AppKeyGenerateCommand.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

/**
 * (c) Gabriel Souza <gabriel.takashi@gmail.com>
 * License (MIT)
 * 
 * PHP version >= 8.0
 */

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class AppKeyGenerateCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = "key:generate";
    protected $description = "Gera a Chave do Sistema [APP_KEY]";

    public function handle()
    {
        $env_path  = $this->laravel->basePath('.env');
        $env_contents = file_get_contents($env_path);
        $new_key = 'base64:' . base64_encode(Encrypter::generateKey('AES-256-CBC'));

        if (Str::contains($env_contents, 'APP_KEY') === false) {
            //Insert
            file_put_contents($env_path, PHP_EOL . "APP_KEY=$new_key" . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        } else {
            //Update
            $current_key = Str::betweenFirst($env_contents, 'APP_KEY=', PHP_EOL);
            file_put_contents(
                $env_path,
                str_replace(
                    'APP_KEY=' . $current_key,
                    'APP_KEY=' . $new_key,
                    $env_contents
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Then on **app\Console\Kernel.php**  insert a entry for the command developed:

```
<?php
protected $commands = [
    //...
    Commands\AppKeyGenerateCommand::class,
];
```

Now you can run the command:
**php artisan key:generate**

Enjoy like a boss ;)